# How is a low quality post review completed?

Tags: discussion, review, review-tools

In [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/168307) case and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/168293), review has been completed by a single "Looks OK" vote. While in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/168272) case it has been completed by two "Looks OK" votes. Is there a reason for it?

Comment: The egotist in me wants to say it was just me, but it really wasn't. What a shame.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number of "Looks OK" votes depends on the number of flags on the post, cf. [this meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190639/263383):

> Each review task requires a minimum number of "Looks OK" reviews (2 on SO, 1 everywhere else) to be dequeued; this number increases by one for each pending flag on the post (edits, closing and deletion dequeue the task in the normal fashion).

Comment: My interpretation: If you really think it shouldn't have been given the "Looks Okay" and you weren't the one to initially flag it, you can always leave a comment explaining your issue with it and flag it again. Then it should require at least 1 more "Looks Okay" to dequeue it